# I want to align the 3 buttons and the little search one with the input not with the label

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

[The problem i need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXQjN.png)

I m using element UI and i need to align the buttons with the input not with the label of component

```
 <el-form ref="form" :model="form" :inline="true" label-position="top">
            <app-input :md="16" :sm="8" label="Căutare Nave" disabled/>
            <el-tooltip content="Cautare" placement="top"><el-button type="primary" size="mini" icon="fas fa-search" class="action-btn" @click="onSearch"/></el-tooltip>
          </el-form>
```

Comment: Wrapping the input and the buttons in an extra tag is the easiest solution, so that they are forced to render on the same line.

Comment: What tag would you suggest?

Comment: Anything that is a block level element. Look at which `<el->` you have available and chose an appropriate one. Worst case a basic <div> ? Or make the element above the buttons be a block instead of inline, so it extends to the place where the buttons are now.

Comment: The same thing happens, the elements keep aligning with the text,which is the label ,NOT with the box

Comment: Have you checked how `:inline="true" label-position="top"` affects your buttons? I don't use this framework, but inline true usually means you don't want elements to extend past what is needed and position top usually means position things to the top which is the reverse of what you seem to be trying to do. Maybe changing one of those two already fixes the issue, so look at the docs of your framework how these two affect your form.

Comment: You can add a `margin-top: 50px` on those buttons to align with the input.